# how show input and hide input at same time with conditon from database ,

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js, livewires

```xml
<select class="form-control" wire:model.defer="production_parametre_fixes_id.0" wire:change="showUnite(0)">
    <option value="0">Choisir</option>
    @foreach ($list_parametres as $item)
        <option value="{{ $item->id }}">
            @if ($item->etape = 'Réception')
                {{ $item->matiere }}  |  {{ $item->unite }}
            @endif
       </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" " wire:model.defer="qte_materiel.0"/>
<input type="time" class="form-control" placeholder=" " wire:model.defer="debut.0"/>
```

I have select from database and I want to

- Show only input for `quantite` if `unite` is equal to `KG` or `l`.
- Show input for `heure` if `unite` is equal to `h`.

How do I do that ?

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: maybe you could do a select of all your inserts, then loop through the query response while using an if statement to check if unite eagle is either KR, l or h.

Comment: so what is wrong with your code? I only see a missing equal in this line:  ($item->etape `=` 'Réception') should be two `==`

Answer (score 0):

If the variable $unite was sent from the controller

```
@if($unite == 'KG' || $unite == 'l')
<input id="quantite" class="form-control"/>
@elseif($unite == 'h')
<input id="heure" class="form-control"/>
@endif
```

But if you wanted to make a decision based on the selected item, then using [JQuery] would be useful

you can visit
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: i have to problem in foreach

Comment: erreur in production_parametre_fixes_id.{{$value}} when i write just production_parametre_fixes_id she is work

Comment: but production_parametre_fixes_id.{{$value}} have a block show/hide input

Answer (score 0):

````
                            <div class="row" x-data="">
                                <div class="col-md-1">
                                    <div class="form-group"  >
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm font-weight-bolder btn-light-primary"  wire:click.prevent="addmat()"><i class="la la-plus"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-prepend">
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-cogs icon-lg"></i></span></div>

                                            <select class="form-control"  wire:model.defer="production_parametre_fixes_id.0" wire:change="showUnite(0)" >
                                                <option  value="0"> Choisir </option>
                                                @foreach ($list_parametres as $item)
                                                    <option value="{{ $item->id }}">
                                                        @if($item->etape = 'Réception' )
                                                            {{ $item->matiere }}  |  {{ $item->unite }}
                                                        @endif
                                                    </option>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                            <label>{{ __('Matériel') }}</label>
                                        </div>
                                        @error('production_parametre_fixes_id')
                                        <span class="form-text text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group" x-show="$wire.showmatiere[0]">
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-prepend">
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket icon-lg"></i></span></div>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" " wire:model.defer="qte_materiel.0"/>
                                            <label>{{ __('Qte') }}</label>
                                        </div>
                                        @error('qte_materiel')
                                        <span class="form-text text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group" x-show="$wire.showheure[0]">
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-prepend">
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-history icon-lg"></i></span></div>
                                            <input type="time" class="form-control" placeholder=" " wire:model.defer="debut.0"/>
                                            <label>{{ __('Début') }}</label>
                                        </div>
                                        @error('debut')
                                        <span class="form-text text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group" x-show="$wire.showfin[0]">
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-prepend">
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-history icon-lg"></i></span></div>
                                            <input type="time" class="form-control" placeholder=" " wire:model.defer="fin.0"/>
                                            <label>{{ __('Fin') }}</label>
                                        </div>
                                        @error('fin')
                                        <span class="form-text text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @foreach ($inputsmat as $key  => $value)

                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row" x-data="">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="input-group input-group-prepend">
                                                <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-cogs icon-lg"></i></span></div>
                                                <select class="form-control"  wire:model.defer="production_parametre_fixes_id.{{$value}}" wire:change="showUnite({{$value}})"  >
                                                    <option  value="0"> Choisir </option>
                                                    @foreach ($list_parametres as $item)
                                                        <option value="{{ $item->id }}">
                                                            @if($item->etape = 'Réception')
                                                                {{ $item->matiere }}  |  {{ $item->unite }}
                                                            @endif</option>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </select>
                                                <label>{{ __('Matériel') }}</label>
                                            </div>
                                            @error('production_parametre_fixes_id')
                                            <span class="form-text text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                            @enderror
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group" x-show="$wire.showmatiere[{{$value}}]" :key="'q-'.$value">
                                            <div class="input-group input-group-prepend" >
                                                <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket icon-lg"></i></span></div>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" " wire:model.defer="qte_materiel.{{$value}}"/>
                                                <label>{{ __('Qte') }}</label>
                                            </div>
                                            @error('qte_materiel')
                                            <span class="form-text text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                            @enderror
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group" x-show="$wire.showheure[{{$value}}]" :key="'d-'.$value">
                                            <div class="input-group input-group-prepend">
                                                <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-history icon-lg"></i></span></div>
                                                <input type="time" class="form-control"  placeholder=" " wire:model.defer="debut.{{$value}}"/>
                                                <label>{{ __('Début') }}</label>
                                            </div>
                                            @error('debut')
                                            <span class="form-text text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                            @enderror
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group" x-show="$wire.showfin[{{$value}}]" :key="'f-'.$value">
                                            <div class="input-group input-group-prepend">
                                                <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-history icon-lg"></i></span></div>
                                                <input type="time" class="form-control" placeholder=" " wire:model.defer="fin.{{$value}}"/>
                                                <label>{{ __('Fin') }}</label>
                                            </div>
                                            @error('debut')
                                            <span class="form-text text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                            @enderror
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-1">
                                        <div class="form-group" >
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger"  wire:click.prevent="removeMat({{$key}})">X</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach```
controller:
public function showUnite($myLine)
    {
        $para = ProductionParametreFixe::query()->where('id',$this->production_parametre_fixes_id)->first();

        if($para->unite == "Kg" || $para->unite == "L"){
            $this->showmatiere[$myLine] = true ;
            $this->showheure[$myLine] = false;
            $this->showfin[$myLine] = false;

        }else if($para->unite == "H"){

            $this->showheure[$myLine] = true;
            $this->showfin[$myLine] = true;
            $this->showmatiere[$myLine] = false ;

        }
       
    }
````